# assembly lea: invalid effective address

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm getting this kind of error:

> beroset-p-637-invalid effective address

Here's a sample code block that contains the error line:

```
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
lea ecx, [record + count*patient + firstName]          ;this one
int 80h
```

Here are my variables from the code block above:

```
patient equ 37
firstName equ 0

count resb 1
record resb patient*5
```

can't the count variable be used in multiplying with the patient?

---

I'm using NASM in x86 Ubuntu 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't multiply by a variable when computing an address.  So you would have to multiply count * patient separately and add that in later.

Comment: @BurnzZ- Nope.  All the arithmetic has to be able to be done at compile time (or be present in a register).

Comment: @BurnzZ - And even then, the scaling factor is limited to 1, 2, 4, and 8.

Comment: "You can't mutiply by a variable".  Well, yes you can.  If you think of "edx" as a variable (after all, its contents are, uh, variable), then the addressing mode [4*edx] is perfectly valid.  More accurately, you can't multiply by the contents of a memory location in an x86 address computation.  OP has to load count into a register and then using an addressing mode that refers to that register.  That probably isn't enough, because he can only multiply by 1/2/4/8 in the address computation.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions! I pre-computed count*patient and stored into esi instead.. lea ecx, [record + esi + firstName] now does not present any errors.

Answer (score 2):

What op really needs to do:

```
 mov eax, count
 imul eax, patient
 lea ecx, [eax + record+ firstName]
```

The reason for the imul is that one cannot multiply a register by a constant other
than 1,2,4,8 in an addressing operation.  And patient is a truly strange constant (37).

You *can* use lea to do complex multiplies by combining various multiples of 1,2,4,8.
Noting that 37 = 32 + 5, he could do the following:

```
 mov   eax, count
 lea   ebx, [eax*8]       ; 8 * count
 lea   eax, [eax+4*eax]   ; 5 * count
 lea   eax, [ebx*4+eax]   ; 4*8*count +5*count
 lea   ecx, [eax + record+ firstName]
```

lea instructions are very fast on modern x86s.  This might outrun the imul computation.
I doubt if that is important to actual patients.

Comment: Did you mean `lea   eax, [eax+4*eax]` for the second line? It seems the third line just overwrites the previous computed result in `ebx`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. No, lea eax... wouldn't fix it. I rearranged to the code to achieve the fix.  No change in cycle count or overall execution time :-}

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing is, BurnzZ has got... `[record`...  in Nasm syntax, the address of `record` a plain "immediate" number, ... `count * patient`. the address of the variable `count`, an immediate, times `patient`, another immediate... Nasm ought to do that! Although it's not what you want (I ASSume). Those errors with Ed Beroset's name in 'em are typically "unusual" errors to get. I don't quite know why you're seeing it here.

What you want (I ASSume) is `[count]*patient` - which won't work, either. But when you do `mov eax, count`, you've got the address of the variable. To work with the "[contents]" of the variable, use `mov eax, [count]`. While either will assemble, the results are quite different!

Answer (score 2):

You need to input variables in separate registers and then multiply them. two variables cannot be multiplied directly.